# How to connect one port to multiple devices?

Tags: ethernet, topology

I'm studying from Lammle book on routing and switching. The setup in the picture is in the book. how can I connect one port of a device to more than one device (as in the figure), and how can I connect two hosts to the same port on a switch or router? I don't know what simulator the book is using, but I'm using Cisco Packet Tracer.
[image]

Another question: how using serial connection is different from the Ethernet connection?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a network is that all devices connected to it can talk to each other. Each device will needs its own port though. Nowadays, you connect a device to the network through a switch port; the switch works as a central concentrator and traffic exchange, directing packeted data to wherever it's intended to go.

The picture is showing a (logical) layer 3 network layout. A physical layer layout would show all the wires and ports.

A COM-style serial port is a connection between exactly two devices (1:1 relation). A network offers many to many (N:N relation).

Note that at the very bottom layer Ethernet isn't too much more than a simple serial connections, but there's a lot of functionality layered on top that makes it work as a network.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about what you are trying to do, you can for example use a layer 2 device  between routers.